# Getting error when trying to compile vue.js on dev server with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, compiler-errors

It looks like it's saying there is no firebase node module, but there is and was working fine until recently.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
./node_modules/firebase/app/index.js

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

[picture of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTtXH.jpg)

Comment: could you please provide more info?

Comment: Have you check that the file `node_modules/firebase/app/index.js` exists under the current directory `.` you are accessing the file. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask